# Start multiprocessing.Process of method in class, from __init__()

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

How can I start a multiprocessing.Process from within `__init__()` of a class, targeting another function in that class? The class itself shall not be a process. `__init__()` shall refer to a class variable assigned in the class, not inside any function.

**Working code:**

```
import multiprocessing as mp
class SomeClass:
    def __init__(self):
        p_process1 = mp.Process(target=self.process1)
        p_process1.start()

    def process1(self):
        while True:
            pass
```

**The code I want:**

```
import multiprocessing as mp
class SomeClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.p_process1.start()

    def process1(self):
        while True:
            pass
    p_process1 = mp.Process(target=process1)
```

**If I now try to run the code I want, I get an error message:**

```
Process Process-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/process.py", line 249, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/process.py", line 93, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
TypeError: process1() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the problem clearly states it: the `multiprocessing` **calls it without parameters, and you however expect one: `self`**. In this case you can solve it like:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

class SomeClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.p_process1.start()

    @staticmethod
    def process1(): # so no parameter
        while True:
            pass
    p_process1 = mp.Process(target=process1)
```

If however **you need a reference to `self`**, there is no other option than to construct the method in a context where you have a reference to `self`. After all if you **fetch `self.process1`**, you **do not get a reference to `SomeClass.process1`**, you obtain a function that is equal to `functools.partial(SomeClass.process1,self=self)`, so you actually have a function where `self` is filled in implicitly.

Comment: In PyCharm, I get an error message, saying that I must have a first parameter. It still runs the way you made it. Should I make it a staticmethod?

Comment: @Andreas: yes that is indeed how to solve the pycharm warning.

Comment: Also, are you sure there are no errors with this way? Is there anything I should instead replace "self" with, instead, such as "csl", if I remember right?

Comment: @Andreas: no that is a [`@classmethod`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1669524/67579).

Comment: Is there any way to make process1 non-callable from outside the class, even when using "@staticmethod" or ("staticmethod(process1)" if in python 2.2/2.3)? Thanks.

Comment: I just saw that I get `TypeError: 'staticmethod' object is not callable` if using @staticmethod.

Comment: @Andreas: I've tested the code and it seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

`process1` is a bound function, it needs class instance as `self` to be the first arg when be called.

If you just want that arch, `@property` can help.

```
import multiprocessing as mp
class SomeClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.p_process1.start()

    def process1(self):
        while True:
            pass

    @property
    def p_process1(self):
        return mp.Process(target=self.process1)

SomeClass()
```

Comment: If I do so, I'll be able to use `SomeClass().process1()`, but not `SomeClass.process1()`, or won't I be able to use any of them? Will process1 only be callable from `__init__()`?

Comment: Also, will this always run `__init__()`?

Comment: Is SomeClass a Object-oriented class and you want to use its instance? If not and you want to call SomeClass.process1(), you must make it as a staticmethod as @Willem Van Onsem said. And you even don't need __init__.

Comment: No. From another class, I start SomeClass, `SomeClass()`. This'll start two processes. Main class: Host, Graphics Class = SomeClass. In the main class, the script is run in a while loop. Called by `Host().startup`. "process1()" is a model of "displayer()" and "handler()". I have problems with threads crashing, or getting a pygame fatal error, segmentation fault. I'm going to create a new question for this, as I don't know how to fix this. Perhaps I can send you the link?

Comment: You can provide the link in comment

Comment: Sorry, but do you know about somewhere else to post the question instead? I've got a warning for these kind of questions. I don't want to become unable to post more.